# Return value of onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am setting `OnTouchListener` on a listview

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

      }
  });
```

My listview behaves very weirdly( hangs between scrolling, very bad scrolling etc) when the return value of this function is true. But it scrolls normal on returning false.

Docs says that it returns `True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.` 
How this is affecting my listview?

Answer (score 0):

If you intercept some but not all touch events in an event stream, the ListView's (very complicated) state machine that handles touch interaction will get into a bad state. You should either intercept every event starting from TOUCH_DOWN to TOUCH_UP or no events.